# Use Box2D 2.2.1 on Flash? WCK, Adobe Crossbridge, Alchemy etc

Tags: flash, box2d, alchemy, flascc

In fact, I have few questions caused by one problem. I use Box2D Alchemy port in one of my Flash gaming projects. This port is compiled from original C++ Box2D v.2.2.0 by guys who made World Construction Kit. However, version 2.2.0 has a nasty bug, which is fixed in 2.2.1. Native AS3 Box2D ports have this bug as well. 
WCK creators have provided an instruction about how to recompile c++ Box2D library using Adobe Alchemy. But Alchemy has been transformed to Crossbridge (Flascc), and the recompiling instructions from WCK are not working with it. Thus, I have these questions:
1. Where to find that old Alchemy which was used by WCK creators? I believe it is still present on someone's HDD.
Or
2. Where to find WORKING Crossbridge Box2D port? Crossbridge package has Box2D library which can be compiled, but I'm unable to use that SWC in my project, it seems that only flash player 11 is supported.
Or
3. Is there another way to use Box2D 2.2.1 in Flash?

Comment: did you ever get anywhere with this?